# HTTPS module error handling when disconnecting from internet in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, node-modules

How can I handle or catch this code or **https** module in node.js? I'm trying to catch this, because if someone will just disconnect from the internet, it will end up in this error. I tried many things, but it didn't work. The website's body is just `v2.2`

Here's the code:

```
const version = "v2.2";

function checkforupdates() {
    try {
        https.get("https://tomkoid.tk/phyc/latestversion.txt",(res) => {
            let updatebody = "";
        
            res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                updatebody += chunk;
            });

            res.on("end", () => {
                if(updatebody.toString()!=version) {
                    console.log("\033[0;33m[Updates] Update " + updatebody.toString() + " found. Download it on GitHub!\033[0m");
                } else {
                    console.log("\033[0;32m[Updates] No update found.\033[0m");
                }
            });
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("error")
    }
}
```

and here's the error:

```
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
    
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN tomkoid.tk
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:72:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'tomkoid.tk'
}

Node.js v17.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just "fixed" it by trying **axios library**, works better.